# Configuring limit to concurrent Asp.Net uses of single login

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

I have an ASP.Net MVC 4 application using Identity 2.0. The application is designed to be deployed as a short-term microsite for industry shows and events (often just a couple of days).

Sometimes we want to restrict traffic to just individuals who have been given a login.

We use a single login (username / password) which is disseminated by the client to their employees who may or may not be on the same network (so IP filtering isn't possible).

In most cases it's not really feasible to generate individual logins so we need to be able to allow multiple uses of the same account.

This works out of the box with Asp.Net Identity but it seems to hit a limit after a certain number of uses of each login. I haven't been able to find a way to configure (or even ascertain) this limit. Does anyone know if / how this can be configured?

Ideally we'd be able to allow any number per login, e.g. 1 / 5 / 100 / unlimited concurrent uses.

.

I found some similar questions but none that really answered my question.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no inbuilt limit on number of users. However you might have expeirenced that only a single login remains active after a period of time (30 minutes by default) and everybody else have to re-login again.

If this is the case, then you have run into `SecurityStampValidator`. Look into your `Startup.Auth.cs` file to see something like that:

```
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager)),
            },
            SlidingExpiration = true,
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
        });
```

For your purposes you can safely dispose of `OnValidateIdentity` event getting anything assigned:

```
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider(),
            SlidingExpiration = true,
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
        });
```

However I'm not 100% sure this is your problem, so this solution might not be the answer.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into that on Monday